# Flutter BLOC navigation onGenerateRoute firing before state arrives

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am building my material app and using the languageBloc to listen to events.
if the selected location is empty I want to navigate to SelectLocationPage();
from there I am selecting a location from a dropDown and in the change event firing the selected language event.

Its working and I can Print() the state and see the selected language
but the **onGenerateRoute** has already finished switch the routes.

```
Widget buildApp(String language, String location) {
    return BlocBuilder<LanguageBloc, LanguageState>(
      builder: (languageContext, languageState) {
        return BlocBuilder<LocationBloc, LocationState>(
          builder: (locationContext, locationState) {

            if(locationState is LocationReadyState) {
              location = locationState.selectedLocation;
              print('selected location ${locationState.selectedLocation}'); ==> **fires second **
            }

            return MaterialApp(
              title: 'Courses',
              locale: _getLocale(languageState, language),
              localizationsDelegates: const [
                AppLocalizations.delegate,
                GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
                GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
              ],
              supportedLocales: const [
                Locale('en'),
                Locale('he'),
                Locale('ru'),
              ],
              initialRoute: '/',
              onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
                return getPageForRouteName(settings, location);
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  PageRouteBuilder getPageForRouteName(RouteSettings settings, String location) {
    print('onGenerateRoute location ${location}'); ==> **fires first location is '' **
    
    if (location.isEmpty) {
      return _buildPageRoute(SelectLocationPage());
    } else {
      switch (settings.name) {
        case '/home':
          return _buildPageRoute(HomePage());
        default:
          return _buildPageRoute(HomePage());
      }
    }
  }
```

I am building my material app and using the languageBloc to listen to events.
if the selected location is empty I want to navigate to SelectLocationPage();
from there I am selecting a location from a dropDown and in the change event firing the selected language event.

Its working and I can Print() the state and see the selected language
but the **onGenerateRoute** has already finished switch the routes.

Comment: Dont put your material app inside BlocBuilder. Better you create a navigator on BlocListener try check this https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterlogintutorial on Tutorials > Flutter > Login > App then check the Widget structure of MaterialApp. On the code example the navigator is placed in BlocListener inside builder of MaterialApp